# The students listed on faculty sites, did a thesis or possibly independent study?

Tags: website, independent-study

Many faculty sites would list some students and many of those students are working or completed a thesis. Do faculty sites list also students who did an independent study?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *independent study* and how is it opposed to *thesis?* Also, are you sure you are talking about faculties and not workgroups or similar?

Comment: I think it would depend heavily on the personal preference of the faculty member.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_study

Comment: By "Independent Study", do you mean an applied project completed to fullfil the requirements for an MS degree instead of completing a thesis?

Comment: @BrianBorchers it is not a requirement. Bs, MS and PhD student can take such course. It is usually an applied project but can be with some research work.

Comment: The term "directed study" is sometimes used for such a project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have only seen one professor who does list students who completed an independent study with him on his website.

However, it appears that he has a very specific goal in doing so. By looking at his website (and previously talking to him) it seems like he is trying to portray his strong motivation to instill students with real world skills by giving them projects similar to what they might work on in industry since a common critique of Computer Science programs is that they don't get students ready for industry jobs.

Other than that, I would say the norm is to only list students that you advise but there isn't a hard rule.

Comment: "list students that you advise", so I assumed that students who took independent study are being advised also?

Comment: @ThomasLee advise often means something very specific to academics/professors.

Comment: @ThomasLee There isn't any requirement for them to also be advisees. In my example, that professor's department has specific people that act as undergrad advisors but they are not professors, so in this case that isn't even possible for undergrads.